# Why do we need to mention schema name in pgAdmin4 tool when querying each time

Tags: sql, postgresql

[Attached the image which shows error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LvcgU.jpg)Why do we need to mention schema name in pgAdmin4 tool every time when querying into tables but its not mandatory in other databases tools like sqldeveloper.
Do we have any option in pgAdmin4 to pointing out to the specific schema?

Comment: you do need to schema qualify a table in Oracle as well, if that table is not owned by the current user. And you don't really have to schema qualify a table in Postgres either. So what exactly is your question. Please **[edit]** your question (by clicking on the [edit] link below it) and add some table definitions and SQL statements that show what problem you have

Comment: Please provide an example of where you *have to* include a schema in Postgres and you would not need one in Oracle.  No particular situation comes to mind.

Comment: in pgadmin4 tool it is required to mention the schema name else it will give error like table or view does not exist, even though pointing to the same schema. Where as this issue wont occur in the sql developer.